What‘s the largest int a modern quantum computer can handle?
I‘m just starting out with this topic and it’s already a bit confusing: I was just wondering, if I could take a really, really big number, let’s say a 256-bit number and add another number to it on a quantum computer (or simulation). There’s no problem doing it on a regular CPU, but on a quantum computer I‘m not sure. Do I need a 256 Qubit register to handle the computation, or is there another way to represent big Integers on a quantum computer? Considering the fact that most providers give access to anywhere between 20-100 Qubits per job, a 256 Qubit register would not be practical.

Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. You can store n-bits number to n qubits, i.e. for 256 bits, you would need 256 qubits. Concerning addition, you can implement classical adder on a quantum computer, however, more efficient way is to use Fourier adder (see here for details: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0008033).

Hi and thanks for the response (and the link). So, it really is not practical to do any kind of computation with really large numbers on quantum computers atm, I guess.

Yes, absolutely. Mainly due to the fact that qubits are now error-prone and it would be hard to retain entanglement among so many qubits. However, you can try to implement toy model, for example to add two 4-bits numbers. I think that under current state of QPU development, it would be possible. Then you can try to increase number of qubits as much as possible.

There are constructions for very efficient adders (in terms of circuit depth, T count, T depth, etc), but generally the limitation of $n$-bit numbers in $n$ qubits is due to some application of Holevo's Theorem. You need $n+1$ qubits to be able to reliably encode the outcome of an addition of two $n$ bit numbers using qubits.
Addition is also classically very easy, its pseudopolynomial time. You don't really get a speed up at all when running it on a quantum device. The only time you would want to add two numbers on a quantum device instead of on a classical one is if the algorithm benefits somehow from adding the registers in superposition.
